# Volume of a vector field embedded in 4D

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Given a surface in 4D, $\bigl(s, t, u(s, t), v(s, t)\bigr)$, if we define vectors between each point $(s, t, 0, 0)$ in some region of the $(s, t)$-plane, and a corresponding point $\bigl(s, t, u(s, t), v(s, t)\bigr)$, it seems that these vectors would define a 3D volume in 4D space, assuming $u(s, t)$ and $v(s, t)$ are continuous and differentiable.

Assuming that is in fact true, how would one calculate the volume?

I don't have a specific application in mind, just a question that occurred to me musing about higher dimensional functions and space.

I appreciate any insight. I'm an engineer, not a mathematician, so the terminology of modern mathematics will lose me quickly, although I have some very minimal exposure to the terminology of fiber bundles.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D$ be the region of the $s$-$t$-plane you're talking about.

Your 3D hypersurface can be parametrized as $p(s, t, r) = (s,t,ru(s,t),rv(s,t))$ for all $(s, t) \in D, r \in [0, 1]$.

The volume of this hypersurface is now a simple triple integral,

$$\iint_{D}\int_0^1 1\sqrt{\left|\det J_p^HJ_p\right|}~dr~d(s,t),$$

where $J_p$ denotes the Jacobian of $p$.

Comment: Thanks very much, your approach really breaks the problem down nicely, and makes sense to me. One question, what does the _H_ annotation on the first Jacobian matrix indicate? Thanks!

Comment: That's the conjugate transpose. Maybe you are more familiar with the notation $J_p^*$ or $J_p^\dagger$. Since we're only dealing with real numbers, you could just use the regular transpose $J_p^\top$ too.

Comment: Thanks, I had a vague recollection of Hermitian matrices, and thought it probably was that, but just wanted to double check. From basic properties of determinants, det(_AB_) = det(_A_)det(_B_), and det(_A_) = det(_A_^ _T_)  (sorry for the formatting, can't figure out how to get superscript in a comment), so we are integrating |det _Jp_| _dr_ _d_(_s_, _t_). What happens if we don't take the absolute value... seems like then we depend on some type of orientation... I'm going to play around with a case I can more readily visualize (_x_, _y_(_x_), _z_(_x_).

Comment: No we aren't. $J_p$ is a $4\times 3$ matrix, it does not have a determinant.

Comment: Ah, ok, right 4x3... interesting. In any case, as I say, I'll play around with the 3D/curve case. Sorry about the formatting mess. Tried to fix it, but took longer than the allowed 5 mins for a comment. I see you are generating sub/super-scripts in comments, but the help seems to indicate you can't. Is there a guide somewhere on how to do it? (New to math stack exchange)

Comment: Stack Exchange uses MathJax, which allows you to write LaTeX math mode directly into your comments, surrounded by the usual $ signs.

Comment: Great, thanks again!